# animating a UIImageView for a chart

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-animation

I am trying to create a simple bar chart from a UIImageView, the code I have so far is:

```
- (void)createNewBarWithValue:(float)percent andImage:(UIImageView *)newBar
{
    CABasicAnimation *scaleToValue = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"];
    scaleToValue.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percent*2.5];
    scaleToValue.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    scaleToValue.duration = 1.5f;
    scaleToValue.delegate = self;

    newBar.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);

    [newBar.layer addAnimation:scaleToValue forKey:@"scaleUp"];
    CGAffineTransform scaleTo = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 1.0f, percent * 2.5);
    newBar.transform = scaleTo;
}
```

All I am doing here is really simple just using transformation to get an animation. The result of the animation can be seen [here](http://www.screenr.com/mrAs).

Now what I want to do is actually to have my final chart like this:

[image]

Now one issue that I see here now is the cornered border on top. I can't do this with what I currently have. So what is the most easiest fix to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newBar.layer.cornerRadius = 5;//or any other value
```

Unfortunately, this will set the radius of all four corners. You might have to hide the bottom two corners and adjust the height accordingly or add another image view on top of the bottom portion of `newBar`.

Comment: I thought of that too..but as you pointed out it will give it for all 4 corners. what is the best way to hide the bottom corners?

Comment: add another image view on top of the bottom portion of newBar in the shape of a red rectangle

Comment: and I just tried that, however it doesn't give me any corner radius.. is there any other settings that I need to change besides that

Comment: You could also use only a single image view with the required BackGround image(with only two rounded corners) and set the height of the frame of the image view according to the value it is supposed to depict